# how to reconnect mongoose default connection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, connection-string

my app.js contains,

```
 exports.getDatabaseConnection = function (dbname, uname, psw) {
mongoose.disconnect();
     mongoose.connect('mongodb://' + uname + ':' + psw + '@localhost:27017/' + dbname);
    }
```

and index.js is

```
router.post('/chooseDb', function (req, res) {
      var temp = req.body.country;
      if (temp === "india") {
        var uname = 'abc';
        var psw = 'abc123';
        var dbname = 'demoDB';
        app.getDatabaseConnection(dbname, uname, psw);
        res.json('done');
      }
       else if (temp === "finland") {
    var uname = 'xyz';
    var psw = 'xyz123';
    var dbname = 'testDB';
    app.getDatabaseConnection(dbname, uname, psw);
    res.json('done');
  } 
    })
```

when first i connect to india then it works fine but second time when i call an chooseDb api with finland it gives an error like,
**Error: Trying to open unclosed connection.**
for mongoose.createConnection i tried schema like

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
    var schema = mongoose.Schema; 
    var db=require('../app.js'); 
    var garageSchema = new schema({ id: String, name: String, address: String }); 
module.exports = db.model('garage', garageSchema);
```

which gives me an error 
**db.model is not function**

Answer (score 0):

Connect using--

```
mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://' + uname + ':' + psw + '@localhost:27017/' + dbname)
```

and not `connect()`.

Comment: i also tried that but when i am using that i can't access any api.

Comment: my schema according to createConnection is like

`var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var schema = mongoose.Schema;
var db=require('../app.js');
var garageSchema = new schema({
    id: String,
    name: String,
    address: String
});

module.exports = db.model('garage', garageSchema); `

this gives an error like..
db.model is not function